# How to render element in React.js from object map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about rendering components from object map. I have a structure like this:

```
const tabs = [
    'tab1': {
        name: 'Tab 1',
        renderComponent: () => <Tab1Component />
    },
    'tab2': {
        name: 'Tab 2',
        renderComponent: () => <Tab2Component />
    }
];
```

I want to access the renderComponent property and render sub component.
Tried with function invocation, React.createElement(), doesn't work.

```
const MyComponent = ({tabs}) => {
    const activeTab = 'tab1';
    return (
        <>
        // How to render it?
        // function invocation?
        // createElement??
            tabs[activeTab].renderComponent();
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: adding curly braces should do the trick: `{ tabs[activeTab].renderComponent() }`

Comment: @PatrickHund I actually have written it like that, but forgot to add it to this mocked examples.
Still it doesn't work.
it says:
tabs[activeTab].renderComponent is not a function

Comment: Yeah, I didn't spot the square brackets in the declaration of tabs, those should be curly. atadnmz's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array declaration is wrong. you should use object or array that includes objects. Try this block.

```
const tabs = {
  tab1: {
    name: "Tab 1",
    renderComponent: () => <Tab1Component />
  },
  tab2: {
    name: "Tab 2",
    renderComponent: () => <Tab2Component />
  }
};
```

Also surround your js code with `{}` like;

```
const MyComponent= () => {
  const activeTab = "tab1";
  return <>{tabs[activeTab].renderComponent()}</>;
};
export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here things i guess you did wrong is
1) adding the single quotes around the object-key
2) writing key-value pairs in array without enclosing it in {}

I think you should do something like this

```
const tabs = [
        {
            tab1: {
                name: 'Tab 1',
                renderComponent: () => <Tab1Component />
            },
            tab: {
                name: 'Tab 2',
                renderComponent: () => <Tab1Component />
            }
        }
    ];

    const activeTab = 'tab1';
```

and

```
const MyComponent = ({tabs}) => {
    const activeTab = 'tab1';
    return (
        <>
        // How to render it?
        // function invocation?
        // createElement??
            tabs[0][activeTab].renderComponent();
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const MyComponent = () => {

const activeTab = 'tab2';

const tabs = [
{'tab1': {
    name: 'Tab 1',
    renderComponent: () => <Tab1Component />
}},
{'tab2':{
    name: 'Tab 2',
    renderComponent: () => <Tab2Component />
}}
```

];

```
  return (
  <div>
    {tabs.map((el) => {
      if (el[activeTab]) {
        return el[activeTab].renderComponent()
      }
    })}
  </div>
```

);
 }